# Shopify draft order custom items - Images

Tags: shopify

I have created an app that uses the Shopify draft order API to create a number of custom items based on interactions in the app so that the customer can checkout their items using Shopify.

I'd like to add image thumbnails to the items, ideally just by supplying a URL to the image file, yet I can not seem to find a way to do this in the [API reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/draftorder).

When creating a draft order via API call using custom line items, rather than existing products, is there a way to add thumbnail images on those custom line items?

Comment: What is your question? If you create a draft order, it consists of products. Products can have and usually have images. You get that for free. Can you at least screenshot where you feel you need to add images to a draft order? Are you criticizing the Shopify Admin? Your question is far from clear and hard to answer.

Comment: see my revised question.   from the documentation, custom line items do not appear to have a way to set a thumbnail image,  I am asking if I have missed something from the REST API docs,  or if anyone knows of a way to assign thumbnail images to these custom line items - which are not products and are not assigned product ID's in the response.

Comment: Ahhh... the short answer is 99% no. You cannot. Playing with fake products (ie) not registered in Shopify, like POS quick sales too, results in a whole lot of missing functionality and nil settings. Images are likely included in that nil category.

Comment: that's what I thought,  but I figured I would reach out here on SO.   thanks.